# xlsxwriter-generated chart cannot be seen in Excel

Tags: excel, libreoffice, xlsxwriter

I recently generated a file using python 2.7, xlsxwriter version 1.1.5. The resulting file has sheets with data and sheets with charts. The file is perfect when I open and view it with LibreOffice 6.2.0.3. However, when I open it with Microsoft 365, I cannot see any charts. All the data worksheets are good. I am very puzzled and any help will be great! Thanks.

PS. When I open the file with Excel, it also warns me that 'We found a problem with some content in your file. Do you want us to try to receover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes'. Not sure whether it is related. I have seen this warning before and it was just a warning.

Here are the codes

import xlsxwriter as xlwt

```
if param['column_to_chart'] is not None:
    for i in param['column_to_chart']:

        chart = wb.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

        chart.set_x_axis({
            'date_axis': True,
            'min' : all_data.date.min(),
            'max' : all_data.date.max(),
            'name': 'date',
            'label_position': 'low'
            })

        column = name_list.index(i)

        chart.add_series({
            'name':       ['data', 0, column],
            'values':     ['data', 1, column, length, column],
            'categories': ['data', 1, datecl, length, datecl]
            })

        chart.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})
        chart.set_size({'x_scale': 1.5, 'y_scale':1.5})

        ws = wb.add_worksheet(i)
        ws.insert_chart('C7', chart, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})
```

Comment: Can you add a small complete exampe that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I added the codes in the original post. I am wondering whether/where I should upload a sample file? Since the file can be viewed in LibreOffice perfectly, my codes are most likely fine.

Comment: The example needs to be complete, and therefore reproducible, in order to debug the issue.

Comment: LibreOffice is in general more relaxed about OOXML element order than Excel. Usually the first step is checking that an OOXML validator does not find some element order problem or unknown attributes. Excel likes to drop all content after discovering any inconsistency in an OOXML file. You can for example check with https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/plugins/gitiles/officeotron